# how to code for updating table data using schedule timer task in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a table column called status - data type is boolean. i want to change status from false to true value 1 hour before a given time(which is saved in a table column), both columns are in a same table. I want to do it without user interaction, i mean by using schedule timer task in ruby on rails.If someone can help me with this, would be much appreciable. **I Am novice in ruby on rails**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a cron job for this.

Try using the [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) Gem for purpose.

```
gem install whenever
```

Refer this [DOC](http://rubydoc.info/gems/whenever/0.7.0/frames) for understanding how easily we can set cron jobs using this gem.